# Auto refresh after DB update

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

Need help for my project. I need to refresh and get the new value from db.

I get the value from DB using this code:

```
conn.Open();
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM message_queue WHERE status = '" + stat + "'", conn);
MySqlDataReader reader;
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    group_name = reader.GetString(2);
    message = reader.GetString(3);
}
```

I need to auto-update it when someone insert new data to the DB. I am so much trouble here. I cant find the right code to do so.

Comment: Call the above code segment again, without user interaction for auto update

Answer (score 0):

try this, after insert of data in DB

```
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
```